# Dynamically select the number of columns to copy over to another sheet in excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

So I have 2 sheets in my Excel file and I am trying to copy only some columns (say 5) to the second sheet. How do I do that? Here is my VBA code

```
Sub button_click()
   Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
   Dim d
   Dim j
   d = 1
   j = 13

   Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("K" & j))

   If i.Range("K" & j) = "Y" Then
   d = d + 1
   e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value

   End If
   j = j + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

So this works right now but the only thing I need changed is, there are about 10 columns but I only want the first 5 to copy over. If I use Columns in addition to the Rows like i.Rows(j).Columns(5).Value it only copies 1 column. I am not sure how to copy all the columns that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your suggested approach, you could specify the range of columns as `.Columns("A:E")` so:

```
e.Rows(d).Columns("A:E").Value = i.Rows(j).Columns("A:E").Value
```

Comment: Works like a charm now! Thanks! :)